# Put matrix rows into a list but keep only the first n entrys in R

Tags: r, list

I have a matrix, which I want to put into a list with each row as one list element. This is done with

```
m <- t(matrix(c(1:9), 3, 3))
splitted_by_row <- split(m, row(m))      #splits matrix by rows
```

But I only want to keep the first i elements of each matrix row with i a vector of indices e.g.

```
indices <- c(1,3,2)
```

Then the output should look like this

```
output <- list(1, c(4,5,6), c(7,8))
output
```

I know this can be done with a for loop, but I am looking for an easier solution, maybe with lapply. I tried

```
l <- lapply(splitted_by_row, function(x) x[1:2])
```

which gives me the first two elements of each list element. How I can change the code, so it uses the index vector instead of 1:2, so I get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Map` that will evaluate the corresponding elements of the `list` with that of 'indices' `vector`.

```
 Map(function(x,y) x[seq(y)], splitted_by_row, indices)
```

---

Or another option would be to use `row/column` indexing based on indices and then `split` the subset elements of 'm' based on the row index.

```
  i1 <- cbind(rep(seq_along(indices),indices), sequence(indices))
  split(m[i1], i1[,1])
```